# EF 6 : Updating DBSet / Entities after calling context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(...)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my project I am currently using

```
context.DbSet<Table>.RemoveRange(…);
context.SaveChanges();
```

to remove multiple entites.

However, this approach is very slow, with most of the time taken in `.SaveChanges()` and no opportunity to improve the situation.

So, I am faced with making a direct SQL Command to remove the items from the Database using

```
context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand(<SQL to remove items>)
```

in the hope this alternative approach will be quicker.

My question is what is the best (most time efficient) way of getting my local DbSet's / Entities back in sync with what is on the database after the Command is executed?

Comment: What is a difference in time between the two deletes?

Comment: The Savechanges will look at every row in dataset and will verify that the change bit is set or not set.  The second method will not check every row.  Instead only sends the changed rows.  So if you dataset has a lot of rows it will take more time to find the items that changed.

Comment: @jdweng, I don't have a time difference yet. At the moment I only know `SaveChanges` takes way too long. So, I am investigating the other approach, but first want to know how to re-sync my DbSets etc.

Comment: The dataset has a bit indicating the rows that changed. So re-sync is checking the changed bit.  In a multi-user database the only way of re-syncing is read everything or having a timestamp so you only need to updates items that changed from last read.  Writing is more complicated since another user may have changed the data.  If the database indicated there were 10 items in stock and you need 8 and another user took out 5 you are going to be short 3 items.

Comment: @jdweng, so what code do I use to read everything. Do I use DbSet<T>.Load() ?

Comment: Or can I set the State of  each entity that is deleted to  State == Detached?

Comment: You are having a Time issue.  So do you want to read everything?  The slowest part of a read from the database is transferring large amount of data.  To minimize the times you only want to read the items that changed.  So if you have a Timestamp of the last time your did a full read then you only have to read the items that changed from last read.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

`DbSet<TEntity>.SqlQuery(String, Object[]) Method` will track, see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbSet_1_SqlQuery_System_String_System_Object___)

Or you can use `FromSqlRaw` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

> Queries that use the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated methods follow the exact same change tracking rules as any other LINQ query in EF Core. For example, if the query projects entity types, the results will be tracked by default.

I can't see why simply requerying the context after doing a delete this way wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi, I'm using EF 6 and not EF Core, so I don't think your comments apply.

Comment: The EF 6 WAS in the original title of this post, but someone has helpfully edited it out.

Comment: Even though EF6 has the DbSet<T>.SqlQuery(…) method, I am deleting items, so I'm not sure what is being returned from this API? The deleted items ?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve then, are you making a lazy loaded entity set and then manually calling a SQL delete and wanting it to refresh? Can't you just create a new EF query and it'll ignore deleted items? Or is it not refreshing?

Comment: Hi, my entities have originally ALL been explicitly loaded locally for speed. The user makes some selections to delete certain ones. Using RemoveRange and SaveChanges takes too long. So, I want to remove the items from the DB another way that (hopefully) is quicker. Hence ExecuteSQLCommand. But, I need my local DbSet to reflect the deletions that have happened on the DB, so my DbSet and the DB are in sync. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I see, in that case I would do a bulk delete query and manually update the entities to reflect the deletions. You should be able to set `item.State = EntityState.Deleted` to reflect that the items have been deleted. But I don't know how this would behave with whatever it is you're planning to do with the entities. If you're going to do things on them that require access to the database you've probably lost your speed boost. And if you're not then you can just concrete cache them and remove entries that you've deleted.